# Проверка на наличие в массиве

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте.

Есть код

```
$type=array(
"фильмы"=>"movie",
"сериалы"=>"serial",
"музыка"=>"music"
);

for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){

preg_match_all('|<a href="blabla/[0-9]*)">(.*)</a>|U',$result[$i][3],$category,PREG_SET_ORDER);

if($type[$category[0][2]] && !empty($category[0][1]))
// найдено
}
```

Как можно проверить наличие значения `$category` (в цикле у каждого могут быть несколько значений) в массиве `$type`? Проблема в том, что в `$category` (берется с помощью `preg_match_all`) - могут быть несколько значений.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить, существует ли значение в массиве, нужно применить одну из этих функций:

```
bool in_array ( mixed needle, array haystack [, bool strict] )
```

**Пример:**

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

Аналог:

```
mixed array_search ( mixed needle, array haystack [, bool strict] )
```